# SEO technics for online directory website

Tags: seo

I am setting up a website that will host offers for supermarkets in the place i live. Now, my question is SEO related. I read everywhere that SEO title and Meta Description should be as unique as possible but in my case i end up with lots of similar (not duplicate but quite similar) content. For example:

Let's say that i am hosting supermarket offers and each supermarket has it's own page.

**Supermarket A (Andy's Supermarket):**

*Seo title:* "Andy's Supermarket New York | MyWebsiteName"

*Meta Description:* "View the latest offers from Andy's Supermarket in NY"

**Supermarket B (Mario's Supermarket):**

*Seo title:* "Mario's Supermarket New York | MyWebsiteName"

Meta Description: "View the latest offers from Mario's Supermarket in NY"

This could be the case for all Supermarkets in the same city, therefore creating a lot of almost identical content. In my case, we are talking about thousands of profiles and i think it's practically impossible to create unique Titles and Meta descriptions for each and every one of them. Is there let's say any technic for websites like mine in order for pages to be SEO friendly?

Thanks,
Charis

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in Google's Webmasters Tools help:

Avoid repeated or boilerplate titles. It’s important to have distinct, descriptive titles for each page on your site. Titling every page on a commerce site "Cheap products for sale", for example, makes it impossible for users to distinguish one page differs another. Long titles that vary by only a single piece of information ("boilerplate" titles) are also bad; for example, a standardized title like "band name - See videos, lyrics, posters, albums, reviews and concerts" contains a lot of uninformative text. One solution is to dynamically update the title to better reflect the actual content of the page: for example, include the words "video", "lyrics", etc., only if that particular page contains video or lyrics. Another option is to just use "band name" as a concise title and use the meta description (see below) to describe your site's content.

Regards,
Charis